# Serialize a Puppeteer page

Tags: serialization, marshalling, puppeteer

## My Problem

I am using [Chrome's Puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer) to automate some personal tasks. Most of these tasks involve logging into a webpage with my credentials and fetching some data.

The process can take up to 5 seconds. This means that my development cycle is pretty long, and I can get throttled pretty quickly.

## My Question

**Is there a way to serialize a Puppeteer webpage after logging in, and run my scripts against a local copy?**

Answer (score 0):

Yes, at any time after the page is opened in puppeteer you can do

```
const html = await page.content();
```

and then save that data to file or html and do anything with it after.

it is possible to open the file later in puppeteer:

```
await page.goto('file://C:/Users/User/data.html');
```

or better still use another node library like [cheerio](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio) or [jsdom](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom) which are supposed to be less expensive to run that puppeteer.

Comment: Wouldn't that only save the html, without he and css?

Comment: Indeed it would. It's possible to save and use CSS too but what about js? Will your site will be able to work offline even with scripts saved? I thought all the necessary scripts would have done their job by the time of saving html.